# Empty Edit/Add windows on jQGrid for MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Although the jQGrid loads properly on the website, clicking the edit and add buttons brings up a window where I can't add the database information. It only shows the submit and cancel buttons on the bottom left.

I'm currently using this function for jQGrid:

```
$('#StudentGrid').jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStudent", "Admin")',
        editurl: '@Url.Action("GetStudent", "Admin")',
        mtype: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        caption: 'Database',
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        prmNames: { page: "CurrentPage", rows: "PageSize" },
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "StudentId",
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records"
        },
        hidegrid: false,
        autowidth: true,
        //width: 1250,
        /*height: 800,*/
        top:100,
        gridView: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        scrollrows: true,
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        pgbuttons: true,
        colNames: ["StudentId", "Name", "Grade"],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'studentId',
                index: 'studentId',
                editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },
                width: 25,
                hidden: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                index: 'name',
                editoptions: { size: 25, maxlength: 20 },
                hidden: false,
                sortable: true,
                width: 25,
                align: "center"
            },
            {
                name: 'grade',
                index: 'grade',
                hidden: false,
                sortable: true,
                width: 25,
                align: "center"
            }
        ],
        postData: {
            StudentId: $("studentId").val(),
            Name: $("name").val(),
            Grade: $("grade").val()
        },
        loadError: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleError('An error occured trying to load the Database.', request, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
        },
        selectTimeout: 0, //for wait to prevent from onSelectRow event firing when actually it is a double click
        onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
            clearTimeout(this.selectTimeout);
            this.selectTimeout = setTimeout(
                function () {

                    if (status) {//select
                        ;
                    }
                    else {       //deselect
                        $('#StudentGrid').jqGrid("resetSelection");
                    }

                },
                250);
        },
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {

        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        add: true,
        del: true,
        edit: true,
        search: false,
        refresh: false,
        addfunc: function (id) {
            updateRow("new");
        },
        editfunc: function (id) {
            updateRow("edit");
        },
        delfunc: function (id) {
            deleteRow(id);
        }
    }).jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 1024, maxWidth: 2048, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: 450 });
```

Both the edit and add buttons use the following function:

```
 //Add new record to grid or edit existing record. 
    function updateRow(id) {
    
        var oper;
        var rowData;

        if (id == 'new') {
            //add requested, set jqgrid value
            oper = 'add';       
        }
        else {
            //edit requested, set jqgrid value       
            oper = 'edit';

            //Get jqgrid row id
            var rowId = $('#StudentGrid').getGridParam("selrow");
            //Re-asign id to rowId
            id = rowId
            //Set row data          
            rowData = $('#StudentGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
    
        }
       
        // Display the edit dialog below to the grid
        var position = getDialogPosition();

        $('#StudentGrid').editGridRow(id, {
            top: position.top,
            left: position.left,
            width: 900,
            height: 'auto',
            mtype: 'POST',
            modal: true,
            autoresizeOnLoad: true,
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            recreateForm: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            ajaxOptions: { cache: false },
            editData: {            
                StudentId: $("studentId").val(),
                Name: $("name").val(),
                Grade: $("grade").val()
            },
            onInitializeForm: function (form) {        
                $('input', form).keypress(
                    function (e) {                    
                        var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
                        if (key == 13) {
                            e.preventDefault();                          
                        }
                    });
            },
            afterSubmit: function (response, postdata, formid) {
                //if action canceled
                var retObj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                if (retObj && retObj.CancelAction > 0) {
                    alert(retObj.Message);
                }

                $("#StudentGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                return [true, '', false]; // no error and no new rowid
            },
            afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {

                //Set fields to only readonly
                $('#studentId').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

                $("#StudentGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                checkForError('An error occured trying to save Student record.', response, null, null, formid);
            },
            beforeShowForm: function (form) {

                //Remove readonly - need to be editable when adding a new code value record to grid/db code values table
                if (id == 'new') {
                    $('#studentId').removeAttr('readonly');
                }          
            },
            successfunc: function (data) {
                return true;
            },
            beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid) {
                return [true];
            }
        });

    }
```

The HTML for the table is:

```
<table style="width:90%;margin:5px;">
    <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>
            <div class="textborder">
                <span>Student Database</span>
            </div>
            <table id="StudentId"></table>
            <div id="pager"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my first time trying to use jQGrid, so are there any parts of the code I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but you should set your fields as editable. this is the property  in colModel -> editable : true like this:

```
    colModel: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            index: 'name',
            editable : true, 
            editoptions: { size: 25, maxlength: 20 },
            hidden: false,
            sortable: true,
            width: 25,
            align: "center"
        },
        ....
```

Check the docs for editing